# Setting size of viewController's view in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

```
UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(0,0,300,70)]; //--(View created)
someViewController *someViewControllerObject = [..]; //View Controller Object created.
[view addSubview:[someViewControllerObject.view]];
```

I want to fit the view controller's view in the UIView's object. The above code doesn't work correctly. Can you help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to just set the frame of the controller view to the bounds of the outer view;

```
UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(0,0,300,70)]; //--(View created)
someViewController *someViewControllerObject = [..]; //View Controller Object created.
someViewController.view.frame = view.bounds;
[view addSubview:[someViewControllerObject.view]];
```

Answer (score 1):

@david's answer is correct to set the initial frame of the view controller's view. set the `autoResizingMask` to get the behavior you want when the superview changes.

```
someViewControllerObject.view.frame = view.bounds;
someViewControllerObject.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[view addSubview:someViewControllerObject.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will make it the same size as your current view.

```
someViewControllerObject.view.frame = view.bounds;
[view addSubview:[someViewControllerObject.view]];
```

Comment: Thanks.. But view is still going out of bounds of UIView object. :(